# Unable to resize /dev/sda1 of GCP postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I created a postgres VM in GCP using this instructions https://joncloudgeek.com/blog/deploy-postgres-container-to-compute-engine/#create-a-compute-instance-running-a-postgres-container with a 10GB disk, everything has worked fine for the last couple of months but I seem to have run out of space on /dev/sda1. So i increased the disk size to 400GB but I can't seem to be able to resize /dev/sda1 using the standard command "sudo growpart /dev/sda 1" I keep getting command not found.

Comment: For most Linux operating systems, the resize is automatic including the disk partition table and file system. Edit your question with details on the disk format, partitions, file systems, etc. Also, check the boot logs for the results of the resize operation (or resize again and then check). https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Comment: Note: I am not sure if the required commands and scripts are present for Compute Engine Container Optimized OS. If not, you **cannot** install them.  You will need to create a new VM.

Comment: It is always a best practise to plan ahead everything before spawning a VM, but sometimes there are cases that can't be avoided or unforeseen events. One of the safest option and also based on my experience, in this kind of situation is spawning a new VM will do the job, as answered by @jwesonga. Resizing disk might post a problem in the future especially if you will do resizing in the middle of your production. If you want to still push on resizing, here is a GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk) on how to resize a persistent disk.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me:

1. Create a machine image of the container.
2. Spin up a new VM based on the machine image created.
3. Delete old VM.

This created a new Postgres VM with 400GB of disk.